# Javascript textContent (whitespace preserving innerText) for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need the IE equivalent of textContent.

Before you jump off the seat of your pants -- innerText is NOT the same as textContent.  innerText parses whitespace as the DOM renderer parses.  textContent parses whitespace as it is written.  I need the latter, but I.E. doesn't support textContent.

**For instance:**

```
DOM Obj:   <p>This  is  an  example.</p>
innerText:   "This is an example."
textContent: "This  is  an  example."
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. IE "normalizes" the spaces even within the `TextNode#nodeValue` property. A while back I'd written this:

```
function textValue(element) { 
    var collector = []; 
    textValueCollector(element, collector); 
    return collector.join(""); 
} 
function textValueCollector(element, collector) { 
    var node; 
    for (node = element.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) 
    { 
        switch (node.nodeType) { 
            case 3: // text 
            case 4: // cdata 
                collector.push(node.nodeValue); 
                break; 
            case 8: // comment 
                break; 
            case 1: // element 
                if (node.tagName == 'SCRIPT') { 
                    break; 
                } 
                // FALL THROUGH TO DEFAULT 
            default: 
                // Descend 
                textValueCollector(node, collector); 
                break; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

And so I thought it might be what you needed, but sadly, no. As you can see in [this live example](http://jsbin.com/uxefow), on IE the extra spaces are left out even though we're walking the text nodes directly, so it only shows a length of 45 where it's 61 in reality (and on other browsers [Chrome, Firefox, Opera]).